# Rabbitmq moving message

Tags: rabbitmq

I have two queues main queue and DLQ. Each of them has its own exchange. These exchange are the topic type.
I process messages in the main queue, when a problem occurs, I redirect them to DLX.

I have a problem with the dlq queue, when I manually move messages to the main queue, they don't want to be executed. Messages are manually forwarded from default exchange (AMQP default), with the routing key having the name of the queue.
I think this is because of a different routing key and exchange.
How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote, it sounds like you are using the RabbitMQ web manager to re-publish.

If that is the case, you can copy the message details (body, header, ...) and paste them into the Exchange view of the web manager.  In the Exchange view, click on the 'main' exchange name and scroll to the publish message section.  Paste in the message data, set your routing key there, and click publish button.

If you are using an amqp client, the process is similar.  The important point is to set the exchange and routing key as desired before you publish.

Comment: Yes I'm using RabbitMQ web manager. Are there any other more convenient ways to transfer messages using the correct routing key and exchange?

Comment: I don't know of a trivial solution.  A shovel could move the message, but it won't set the exchange/routing key as you want.  You could write an amqp client that consumes messages from your DLQ and 'corrects' faulty messages and republishes to correct exchange.